# Creating a private folder in home directory of each user

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu

I am trying to create 100 users for a class and  so that could write compile and and run their projects over ssh.

I am assigning default a password say '123' to all users(they could change it later themselves) 
I've set soft and hardlimits on disk usage (8mb and 16mb)

Now,  I was thinking of creating a private folder in their home folders which couldn't be read by anyone else 
Turns out, this script gives 'me' instead of the user, the read write and execute to all the private folders

Here's what the script looks like.

```
 for i in {1..100}
 do
    useradd -m -g student $i
    mkdir /home/$i/private               //Creating a private folder
    chmod -R 700 /home/$i/private        //

    echo "$i:123" | sudo chpasswd
    setquota -u $i 9 18 0 0  /
done
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine, you just have to change the owner of the new directory:

```
 for i in {1..100}
 do
    useradd -m -g student $i
    mkdir /home/$i/private               //Creating a private folder
    chmod -R 700 /home/$i/private        //
    chown $i:student /home/$i/private            <------------------ new line

    echo "$i:123" | sudo chpasswd
    setquota -u $i 9 18 0 0  /
 done
```

Note that as you are the user doing `mkdir`, the new dir belongs to you.

Note also that I used `chown $i:student` so that the owner will be the user and the group will be `student`, which happens to be the group you are adding these users to.